# Number of checkboxes checked using javascript, angularJS and bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a tag using a class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart" from bootstrap. And I would like to add on the bottom right the number of check-boxes checked and to display the new number each time the user checked or unchecked on of the box. My glyphicon is in the header and the check-boxes are displayed in a ng-repeat loop. I have some difficulty with angularjs and I don't really know how to do it, if I have to use a directive, or a controller. If you got any kind of help for it I will take it.

My view where are check-boxes itemSearch-result.js there is no controller, only directives

```
<tbody>
     <tr ng-repeat="item in chart.items>
         ...
         <td>{{ ad.price | ypcurrency }}</td>
         <td> <input type="checkbox"> </td>
     </tr>
</tbody>
```

My header view, with a controller: ng-controller="HeaderCtrl"

```
<ul class="nav-right pull-right list-unstyled">
        <li>
          <a class="toggle-min" href>
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></i>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown text-normal nav-profile" dropdown>
            <a href class="dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle>
                <span class="hidden-xs">
                    <span>{{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}</span>
                </span>
                <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
            </a>
        </li>
        ...
</ul>
```

Comment: should be failry easy to loop through the model that the checkboxes `ng-model`'s are bound to. Show us some markup

Comment: Is your header and the shopping cart list all inside one controller? Or do you have it broken up as header, details etc? I had a similar app and i used  a service which calculated the total items in the cart and displayed it in the detail page as well as the header cart icon. If you give me more information on how your page is structured, I can help you with code

Comment: I update some things but my code is so long that i can't show you evreything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of ways to accomplish this.  First of all, make sure you know the difference between a directive and a controller shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22920220/1518802).

Look into using [events](http://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/) as you need to talk to another controller/module.

That way you can create a service that gets injected into both controllers to update the amount of selected items (as opposed to using $rootScope) and set it on your glyphicon. (Not sure about that without seeing your code)