# Difference between and when to use controllers vs directives?

Tags: angularjs

I'm struggling to understand what the purpose of a controller is. I understand that it is how you reference things but since you can throw it in a directive, is there ever a scenario where you would want to use ng-controller for a specific section in your html rather than creating a directive that has a controller built in?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18757679/angularjs-directives-vs-controllers

Comment: Great question! In Angular 2.0 ng-controller was remove in favor of only using controllers attached to directives. The controllers in MVC are your 'glue' between models and services so the less 'glue' you can get away with using the cleaner your codebase will be. Services should handle getting and storing data and directive display that data. Having your directives directly call a service and use data you reduce your scope pollution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> is there ever a scenario where you would want to use ng-controller for a specific section in your html rather than creating a directive that has a controller built in?

Yes, absolutely yes.

- Use a directive when the goal is to *manipulate* the DOM.
- Use a directive when you want to create a reusable *component*.
- Use a controller when all you need is to *bind values* to the DOM.

There's probably a hundred other cases that could be made for either of the two approaches, but I believe this should be enough to justify the use of one over the other.

As for the differences between the two, look at the question that @yvesmancera already pointed you to ([angularjs-directives-vs-controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18757679/angularjs-directives-vs-controllers)).

> In Angular, a Controller is defined by a JavaScript constructor function that is used to augment the Angular Scope.
>
> When a Controller is attached to the DOM via the ng-controller directive, Angular will instantiate a new Controller object, using the specified Controller's constructor function. A new child scope will be created and made available as an injectable parameter to the Controller's constructor function as $scope.

---

> At a high level, directives are markers on a DOM element (such as an attribute, element name, comment or CSS class) that tell AngularJS's HTML compiler ($compile) to attach a specified behavior to that DOM element or even transform the DOM element and its children.