# What can controllers do that directives can't?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm just beginning AngularJS. When I first started reading about it, it seemed from the beginner tutorials that the controller is the basic building block of an angular app. However, since learning about directives, I've been creating my own little Angular app with only directives, literally not a single controller. I can't see why I would ever need a controller.

The only thing I've ever seen done with a controller is add variables to scope:

```
angular.controller("myController",
    function($scope)       
    {
        $scope.x = 5;
        $scope.y = 6;
    }
)
```

But I can do that with a directive too, by using the `scope` argument passed to the link function.

Is there something else that can be done with controllers, which can't be done with directives? Or at least something which is easier to do with controllers than with directives?

For example, if I just needed to populate scope with some variables `x` an `y`, I can just do:

```
angular.directive(
    "myDirective",
    function()
    {
        return {
            link: function(scope, element, attributes)
            {
                scope.x = 5;
                scope.y = 6;
            }
        };
    }
);
```

Comment: What does your app do that you don't have a single controller…? You can build the frontend in just HTML with angular directives and such, but if you want that to *do* anything halfway complex you need to write actual Javascript code, which goes into controllers…

Comment: Note: There are [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31481000/difference-between-and-when-to-use-controllers-vs-directives?noredirect=1&lq=1) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37069110/what-is-the-difference-between-controller-and-directives-in-angular-js?noredirect=1&lq=1) about controllers vs directives on stackoverflow, but none of them specifically ask for an example of something that can be done with controllers but not directives. I didn't find the answers to any of those questions helpful.

Comment: @deceze Can you give an example where the code couldn't just be put in the link function of the directive?

Comment: Please give some concrete example of how _you_ are using directives vs. controllers!

Comment: @JackM in early ui-router you can specify controller for page, but not a directive. In current ui-router you can specify component. Also notice that ng-controller is also a directive...

Comment: You _could_ build an entire app with directives, but that doesn't mean you should. You could also travel to the grocery store in a helicopter if you wanted to, but there are better ways. If all you have is a hammer...

Comment: @deceze [This](https://github.com/geajack/Recipes) is a tiny app I've been making to learn Angular, it just creates some directives to represent GUI elements. Basically you can think of it as a shopping list app (type "ingredients" into a list, delete them, modify them).

Comment: Please post some concrete short examples into your question, is what I meant.

Comment: @deceze Sure. I edited in an example of how I would do with a directive what the controller in the question does.

Comment: If all you're doing is initialising variables on the scope… then yeah… the difference is somewhat academic. Start writing controllers as classes, using services through dependency injection, and you may start to see a difference. In short, a controller is a persistent object which lives side-by-side with a specific view/template and is bound to it in some fashion. `link` is merely a one-time callback function. They can partly be used for the same purpose, but are quite different in their life cycle. A full explanation could be quite lengthy…

Comment: @deceze Is it not possible to give a "minimal example" of a controller doing something that would be impossible (or more difficult) to accomplish with a directive? I mean you say a controller is persistent, but so are the variables you store in `scope` in the link function (or local variables retained in a closure). Plus directives have isolate scopes which controllers don't AFAIK...

Answer (score 1):

You can probably write pretty much everything your app needs in a `link` callback, sure. Note that I'm not even calling it a directive, I'm saying a *`link` callback*. A directive is something that defines a custom HTML tag and its associated functionality, a `link` callback is merely a specific part of that.

The thing is that this is little more than working with jQuery, or using `addEventListener` to attach behaviour to HTML elements. On the other hand, you can write controllers as classes instead of procedural code manipulating the `scope` object. Here's my preferred style to write [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs) in [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript):

```
export default class WidgetController {
    error: string;

    static $inject = ['$state', 'FooService', 'BarService'];

    constructor(
        protected $state: angular.ui.IStateService,
        protected foo: FooService,
        protected bar: BarService
    ) {}

    get fooValue() {
        return this.foo.baz;
    }

    doSomething() {
        this.error = null;
        this.bar.getSomething().then(data => {
            if (data.error) {
                this.error = data.error;
            } else {
                this.$state.go('success');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

A template for this might look like this:

```
<h1>{{ $ctrl.fooValue }}</h1>
<button ng-click="$ctrl.doSomething()">Do!</button>
<p>{{ $ctrl.error }}</p>
```

The controller may be attached to the template using the ui-router:

```
import WidgetController from 'widget-controller';

module.config(['$stateProvider', ($state: angular.ui.IStateProvider) => {
    $state.state('widget', {
        controller: WidgetController,
        controllerAs: '$ctrl',
        templateUrl: '/templates/widget.html',
    });
}]);
```

Or as a component:

```
module.component('widget', {
    templateUrl: '/templates/widget.html',
    controller: WidgetController,
    bindings: {
        error: '@'
    }
});
```

Or using `ng-controller` or in a number of other ways.

It gives you more flexibility. It allows you to *test* the controller pretty easily in isolation, since it's just a regular class. It allows you to reuse the controller for different templates, and the same template for different controllers (yes, this can actually be really useful). It's IMO more readable and easier to understand. Specifically using `$ctrl.` in the template prevents you from building too interdependent nested scopes and explicitly binds the template to use only its controller, instead of some implicit scope.

There are many ways to do things, but the one thing I have figured out over time is that dealing with the `scope` object is both verbose and annoying, and can easily lead to spaghetti code. So, moving away from that, you're soon arriving at controllers as objects.

Comment: But what's the difference between using `$ctrl` and just making directives with isolated scope?

Comment: Not much. The main issue in this entire thing is that you're somewhat conflating several things. A *directive* is one of the ways in which a template can be bound to some sort of controller. A slightly tweaked variant of it is a component. A ui-router state is a not very different way to do somewhat of the same thing. The comparison is really whether you should do things in a `link` callback by attaching properties to the `scope`, or whether you should write things as a class/instantiable object. (cont.)

Comment: And here again, it's *possible* to modify the `scope` in a one-time callback to get basically the same result as a controller, it's simply not what it's meant for. The `link` function is supposed to be a low-level function working close to the HTML bare-metal, setting up event handlers on HTML elements or such. Controllers are supposed to be more abstracted from those low-level details. It's hard to illustrate why that distinction really matters unless you've shot yourself in the foot in a really complex app where you've messed up the distinction to your detriment.

Comment: I may revise this answer to talk more about the conflation between ways of binding a controller to a view, and using the `link` callback instead of a controller. This answer is admittedly currently focussed on the wrong thing.

Comment: This may be off-topic, but another thing that bothers me is that with directives, you can isolate them from the surrounding app by passing data through attributes. Can you do something similar with controllers? The only way to get data into a controller from the outside that I know of is to have the controller constructor grab it off the $scope service, but that means the controller has to know what the external variables are called - unlike with directives and attribute binding.

Comment: You’re again conflating things. A controller and a directive are apples and oranges. Perhaps most to the point: *a directive can have a controller!* I’ll revise this answer later…