# how do you re-use templates in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates

How can you re-use a template? Consider the following javascript object:

```
{
    MyName: '',
    Address: {
        Street: ''
    },
    MyEmployer: {
        CompanyName: '',
        Address: {
            Street: ''
        }
    }
}
```

And a template file at `/templates/myTemplate.html`:

```
<div ng-app="someapp" ng-controller="somecontroller">
    MyName: <input type="text" ng-model="MyName" />

    <div ng-include="'/templates/address.html'"></div>

    My Company: <input type="text" ng-model="MyEmployer.CompanyName" />

    <div ng-include="'/templates/address.html'"></div>
</div>
```

Here is how I would imagine the address template file at `/templates/address.html` would look like:

```
<div>
    Street: <input type="text" ng-model="Street" />
</div>
```

As you can see i'm trying to re-use the address template here. So how do you pass the proper objects to this template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer**
I managed to solve the problem myself and wanted to post it here for the next person who might be looking for the same treat.

**My Solution**

In my OP I had a model object with two addresses, one for the person's home and another for his/her employer. So taken the same object model and same address template still at `/templates/address.html`, we can add two additional controllers:

```
app.controller('personAddressController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   $scope.Street = function(newValue) { return arguments.length ? model.Address.Street = newValue : model.Address.Street; }
}]);
app.controller('companyAddressController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   $scope.Street = function(newValue) { return arguments.length ? model.MyEmployer.Address.Street = newValue : model.MyEmployer.Address.Street; }
}]);
```

And `ng-include` usage for our address template:

```
<div ng-include="'/templates/address.html'" ng-controller="personAddressController"></div>

<div ng-include="'/templates/address.html'" ng-controller="companyAddressController"></div>
```

Also we need to modify our address template:

```
<div>
    Street: <input type="text" ng-model="Street" ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }" />
</div>
<!--or add a form if you have more fields like i did-->
<form ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }">
    <div>
        Street: <input type="text" ng-model="Street" />
    </div>
</form>
```

More information on `ng-model-options` and setter/getter (bottom of the page): https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel

Though watch out when adding a form since `enter` key will do a submission by default, but you can easily control that if you wanted to.

Lastly, you can use directives to do all of this as someone has suggested already, but you would end-up using angular directives as controllers and according to angular they aren't meant for that, more info here: [AngularJS - Directives vs Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18757679/angularjs-directives-vs-controllers)

Answer (score 1):

After struggling during months with that problem, I now use that way to avoid duplication of template:

In the controller:

```
$scope.myelement = {...};
$scope.myelements = [{ ...}, { ... }]
```

In the template myelement.html :

```
{{ myelement.name }} {{ myelement.anything }}
```

In a template:

```
<div ng-include="'myelement.html'"></div>  <!-- $scope.myelement is used --> 
<div ng-repeat="myelement in myelements track by $index"></div> <!-- $scope.myelements[$index] used myelements.length times -->
```

If you wanna specify another variable you can do:

```
<div ng-include="'myelement.html'" ng-init="myelement = SomeScopeVariable;"></div>
```

But in that case the ng-init is only called when the `ng-include` is compiled. And you won't be able to change the 'myelement' inside it, you will only be able to modify its attributes. I don't recommand to use ng-init, except in case you just want to modify / visualize a specific element in your controller. If you want to remove it or create another one, don't use ng-init.

Comment: A few things. first i'm not trying to repeat a template for an array of any sort. second, using `ng-init` will require hard-coding the variable name inside the template and that defeats the purpose of re-using it. Essentially i was hoping for something like what KnockoutJS does: template options!

Comment: @Hani: in your code there is a mistake: you always write ng-model="MyName" etc... but it should be ng-model="myelement.MyName"

Comment: MyName is a property of `$scope` object, although if myelement.MyName was part of `$scope` object then you would do what you've suggested.

Comment: @Hani: you don't have to store an object in $scope directly, but in an attribute of $scope like $scope.myelement. By doing this, you can easily reuse the template in different part of the project. Another tip: in ng-model, if you don't have a dot "." it's that you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

`ng-include` share the same controller and the same data.

So a solution probably will be to think of something else. Maybe a template directive. You can pass a template and also different values to it.

```
// Directive
app.directive('addressTemplate', function() {
    return {
        templateUrl: '/templates/address.html',
        scope: {
            street: '='
        }
    };
});

// My template
<address-template street="MyEmployer.Address.Street"></address-template>

// Template
<div>
    Street: <input type="text" ng-model="street" />
</div>
```

Comment: Well if that's the case, i wouldn't be using Angular. Any UI framework should promote the code reuse and that loosly means template re-use. here http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html

Comment: Well I just created a custom directive that I can use and modify however I want to reuse my code as much as I want.

Comment: @Hani: Each time you will have to wrap an async call for a reusable item, you will have to wrap it in a directive. Frameworks like ionic define lots of generic directives.

Comment: You would end up with hundred directives if you don't know how to structure them and how to use them. Directives could be very flexible and a great tool for any purpose. No need to insult my example. I'm just trying to help you and give you more options :)

Comment: @Histro Further more, my OP is just a dummy example. I would end up writing a few hundred directives for purpose of reusing variety of templates because i have a few thousands of domain objects with variety of property names. I doubt that should be the case?