# angularJS dynamic generated li tag with ng repeat creating multiple ul tag

Tags: angularjs

The following code contain a input box, a radio button and a button.

When the button is clicked, it will generate one more inputbox and radio button. All the radio button are under the same name.

```
  <ul id = "listOfAnswers" ng-repeat="i in addQuestion.loop(addQuestion.numOfChoice) track by $index">
    <li>
        answers:<input type="text"/>
        correct:<input type="radio" name="correctChoice" value ={{$index}}/>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button ng-Click="addQuestion.numOfChoice = addQuestion.numOfChoice + 1">add more choices</button><br/><br/>
```

When I open it in browser, while it is displaying properly when I inspect it, it is showing

```
<ul ..>
  <li> [...] </li>
</ul>

<ul .. >
  <li> [...] </li>
</ul>
```

so every repeat it generate another ul tag. The problem is Im trying to get all the li item at the end and ajax it, by using `getElementById("ul-tag-id").children`. I can assign a class name to each li item, but I prefer the previous method, neater.

Am I doing something wrong here? Also I just learn that there are custom directive, I cant decide when I should put the stuff in controllers when I should put them in a directive. A lot of tutorial I find online are outdated, I'm not sure which to follow, any advice?

Comment: Use directives when you need a reusable component.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ng-repeat` should be used on the element that you want to be repeated. Looks like you need to move it to the `li` element.

Some learning resources:

- [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18757679/angularjs-directives-vs-controllers) - Specifically your question
- [Official AngularJS tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) - AngularJS basics, up-to-date with the latest version.
- [ng-book](https://www.ng-book.com/) - Controllers, scopes, directives, services... Everything is very well explained.

Comment: o that's embarrassing, thanks. Would you be able to answer my second question? or does it require a very lengthy answer?