# how to close angular bootstrap popver on window resize

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code for a popover to provide two options, however when I resize the page, i want to close the popover

Below is my popover code

```
<div class="form col-xs-12 noPad left">
    <h2 class="page-title">Projects
        <span class='icon-settings-big' style='cursor:pointer;float:right;margin-top:-10px;' title='settings' uib-popover-template="dynamicPopoverPageSettings.templateUrl" popover-placement="bottom-right" popover-class="settingsClass"></span>
    </h2>
</div>
```

Comment: how're you `trigger`ing your `popover`?

Answer (score 0):

us the resize binding:

**HTML:**

resize property:

```
<div ng-app="App_Name" ng-controller="App_Controller" resize> </div>
```

**Angular:**

use a directive:

```
var app = angular.module('App_Name', []);

function App_Controller($scope) {
    /* some other code */
}

app.directive('resize', function ($window) {
    return function (scope, element) {
        angular.element($window).bind('resize', function () {
            /* close the popover */
        });
    }
})
```

Technically, you dont need to inject the scope in the directive, but you would have access to it like that.

closing your popover depends on your strucutre. I prefer the simple way with jquery: `$('#POPOVER_ID').popover('hide');`

Comment: why is it that i see a separate `controller`?

Comment: @manish It isn't a controller, it is a directive, see this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18757679/angularjs-directives-vs-controllers#answer-22920220

Comment: that post of fine, because of `ng-controller="App_Controller" `I had to ask, you don't have to do it that way, your directive by itself can refer to that, it needn't be be explicitly mentioned. :)

Comment: this is my controller var w = angular.element($window);
 
   w.bind('resize', function () {

   
$('.settingsClass').popover('hide');
});

Comment: its not working for me.Not sure where am i doing wrong.

Comment: you do not need to put this code IN the controller. the directive is outside of the controller itself

Comment: maybe the $('#POPOVER_ID').popover('hide'); doesn't work here. try to debug and see if you even reach the resize function. If yes, then the popover needs to be closed differently